# Android merging two Firestore calls into single callback

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently querying a collection on Firestore link this one:

```
val missionsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("/customers").document(user.customerId).collection("missions")
    .orderBy("deadline")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("deadline", startDate)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("deadline", endDate)
    .whereArrayContains("staffs", user.id)
```

Just to clear things up, on my mission document, the fields are, respectively:

**deadline**: a timestamp

**staffs**: an array of strings with the staffs ids

So what I'm currently fetching are **all missions from a certain period in time (*based on the deadline*) that belongs to a certain staff**.

But now, I also have to fetch **missions that are visible to all staffs (*using the same deadline rule*)**, which, on this application, means **all mission where this array is empty**.

Since I don't have a method called `.whereArrayIsEmpty("staffs")`, I created a field on my document called "visibleToAllStaffs", which is a boolean field, but I have a deeper problem. Firebase won't allow a OR statement.

I know I can call the first query and, on it's success callback, call a second one, but I would like to use something better than this, perhaps RxJava or Coroutines, but I'm getting stuck on how I could do this.

So, my questions are:

1) Is there a native way (using only firebase) for me to group two queries that fetches data from the same collection having only one callback for error and one for success (where, in this case, the success will bring both datas)?

2) If not, can I solve it with RxJava or Coroutines? How?

### EDIT

Just giving some more explanation, my second call would be:

```
val missionsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("/customers").document(user.customerId).collection("missions")
    .orderBy("deadline")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("deadline", startDate)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("deadline", endDate)
    .whereEqualTo("visibleToAllStaffs", true)
```

The `missionsCollection` variables are objects of type [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query). On those objects I can call a `get()` method which returns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) object of [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) (`Task<QuerySnapshot>`)

With this `Task<QuerySnapshot>` object, I can add some callbacks (success and error, for example), like this:

```
missionsCollection.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    val missions = documentSnapshot.map { it.toObject(Mission::class.java) }
    // do something with the list
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Do something
}
```

My biggest problem with coroutines was trying to merge the callbacks, because I imagine I'll have something like this:

```
.merge(getMissionsCollection(), getSecondMissionsCollection())
.addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    val missionsFromBothCalls = documentSnapshot.map { it.toObject(Mission::class.java) }
    // do something with the full list
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Do something
}
```

but I couldn't find any example like this one (where the methods return a "observable" and not the List I need and I got stuck on how to merge them together.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try using coroutines and if I am not mistaken I should look more less like this, so each suspend fun will wait until it finishes and then start the next in the launch block.

```
suspend fun getMissionsCollection() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
     .collection("/customers").document(user.customerId).collection("missions")
     .orderBy("deadline")
     .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("deadline", startDate)
     .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("deadline", endDate)
     .whereArrayContains("staffs", user.id)
     .get().await().result

suspend fun getSecondCollection() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
     .
     . 
     .
     .get().await().result
```

and then using

```
launch {
   val missionCollection = getMissionsCollection()
   val secondCollection= getSecondCollection()

   // merge collections or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but my biggest problem with coroutines was trying merge both callbacks, because the `get()` method gives me an Task<QuerySnapshot>, not a List<Mission>. If I edit my question explaining how my second query should be and also detailing a little more about the return of the get method, could you help me with this too?

Comment: Cant promise, lets try:D

Comment: I edited the question as much as I could. I really apendicite you what you already answer, but being to fresh with coroutines is making it hard to understand some concepts, like merging two suspend functions that returns an "observable"

Comment: what do you mean by observable? do you want to see if data has changed in the database ? Did you see realtime updates in firestore -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: I was actually using this implementation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 0):

Hello Brother you can see my example.

```
    private void firebaseTasks() { 

    String audioLink = ""
    String videoLink = ""

    Task taskA = firebase.collection("collectionA").document("docPath")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                arrayA.addAll((ArrayList<String>) Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.get("your Field Name")));
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
    Task taskB = firebase.collection("collectionB").document("docPath1")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> arrayB.addAll((ArrayList<Boolean>) documentSnapshot.get("your Field Name")));

    Task taskC = firebase.collection("collectionC").document("docPath2")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> arrayC.addAll((ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("your Field Name")));

    Task taskD = firebase.collection("collectionD").document("docPath3")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> arrayD.addAll((ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("your Field Name")));

    Task taskE = firebase.collection("collectionE").document("docPath4")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> videoLink = documentSnapshot.getString("your Field Name"));

    Task taskF = firebase.collection("collectionF").document("docPath5")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> audioLink = documentSnapshot.getString("your Field Name"));

    Tasks.whenAllComplete(taskA, taskB, taskC, taskD, taskE,taskF)
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                // The task is completed 
            });
}
```

// try the following below if you want to use it in a loop.

```
    public class FirebaseTaskListExample {

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    // only these import carefully
    //    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    //import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

    public void generateTasks(){
    ArrayList<Model> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Task<?>> taskArray = new ArrayList<>();

    collection.add(new Model("aCol","aDoc","aChild"));
    collection.add(new Model("bCol","bDoc","bChild"));

    for(int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++){
        Task<DocumentSnapshot> task =                 getTask(collection.get(i).collectionName,collection.get(i).docName);
        int finalI = i;
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Log.e("Firebase Task 
    Info",documentSnapshot.getString(collection.get(finalI).childDoc));
            }
        });
        taskArray.add(task);
    }

    // after add all tasks set callback

    Tasks.whenAllComplete(taskArray).addOnSuccessListener(new 
     OnSuccessListener<List<Task<?>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Task<?>> tasks) {
         // all task is completed
            Log.d("Firebase Task Info","Task Success");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });

}

    public Task getTask(String col, String doc){
    return firestore.collection(col).document(doc).get();
}

    class Model{
    String collectionName;
    String docName;
    String childDoc;
    Model(String collectionName, String docName,String childDoc){
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
        this.childDoc = childDoc;
        this.docName = docName;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can I put this code in for loop? in order to generate number of tasks programattically.

Comment: Yes, you can generate number of tasks programatically. I also updated code,  you can see the example. You